# PHPUnit - Test fopen, fwrite return

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I used PHPUnit to test a function with contents:

```
$fp = fopen($file_path,'wb');

if( $fp === false ) {
     ...
}

$ret = fwrite($fp, $content) ;
if( $ret === false ) {
     ...
}
```

I have a problem, **fopen** always return a *resource* and **fwrite** always return a *integer* value but i want them return **FALSE**.
How should i do?
Thank everyone :).

Comment: I don't understand! what do you want to test ? `fopen`, for example, will return `false` is the file doesn't exist and you can suppress the warning by using `@`!

Comment: Thank you, when the file doesn't exists, my code can't run **if( $fp === false )**, i don't know reason.

Comment: Try to change `wb` to `r` !

Comment: Thank you, but same result.

Comment: Because with `wb` the file was created try to change the file name.

Comment: So try to write to a file you don't have access to. Like `/this/path/definitely/does/not.exist`

Comment: Thank all, i changed mode from wb to r or set permission not write but received same results.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a FileHandler class encapsulating all the file handling parts so you can inject a stub for it in your tests and setup the stub to return what you want in the different tests. You don't have to test that library functions work, only that you are calling them as expected